# Web Api parameter design style

Tags: java, spring, api

I try to design a simple web api using Spring. There is only one parameter which is an array of string, the my api could looks like this

```
   public String test(String[] pars){}
```

or there is another way, I just take one string as a parameter and split using a separator like ";" or ":",the my api would be this:

```
     public String test(String par){ 
        String pars = par.split(":");
       }
```

I just want to know the pros and cons of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is the best for many reasons.

The most important one is that the default way for HTML/HTTP to send multiple values for the same parameter, is to send the parameter multiple times. This is used for checkboxes and multi-select options lists in HTML forms.

Another good reason is that this is supported out of the box by Spring WebMvc:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String test(@RequestParam("pars") String[] pars){}
}
```

To pass an array to this you use the URL

```
http://yourhost/test?pars=par1&pars=par2&pars=par3
```

Obviously the disadvantages of the second method that you suggested is that this is not the standard way in which HTML/HTTP communicates multi-value parameters, and it is also not supported by Spring WebMvc out of the box.

The advantage of the second method could be that the URL would be a bit shorter, which is only an issue when you are doing GET requests, not with POST requests. But if you keep the parameter name short, this is not a major issue.